# Changed codomain of inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

If codomain of  $\arcsin(x)$ is $(\pi/2 , 3\pi/2)$  and codomain of $\arccos(x)$ is $(\pi , 2\pi)$ then what should be $\arcsin + \arccos$ equal to ?

I thought of putting $x = \sin \theta$

But then stuck , what to do next ?

Comment: The standard ranges are shifted by $\pi,\;$  therefore the sum is $5\pi/2$

Comment: @gammatester how can you say this

Comment: The standard range for $\arcsin$ is $[-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{1}{2}\pi];$ you want it to be $[\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{3}{2}\pi],\,$ so there is a shift of $\pi$. Similar for $\arccos,\;$ and since for the standard functions you have $\arcsin x + \arccos x = \frac{1}{2}\pi,\;$ the sum of your shifted functions is $\pi + \pi + \frac{1}{2}\pi = \frac{5}{2}\pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta=\sin^{-1}x$. Then,
$$x=\sin\theta$$
$$x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)$$
$$\cos^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)\right)$$

Since $\theta=\sin^{-1}x$, we have $\theta\in\left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$.
$$\frac{\pi}2-\theta\in(-\pi,0)$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta+2\pi\right)$$
where $\frac{\pi}2-\theta+2\pi\in(\pi,2\pi)$.

Thus,
$$\cos^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta+2\pi\right)\right)=\frac{5\pi}2-\theta=\frac{5\pi}2-\sin^{-1}x$$

$$\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x=\frac{5\pi}2$$

Comment: Can we draw graph of arccos(cosθ)

Comment: @user101522 Yes you can. Is that what you meant by the question?

Comment: how can we draw it

Answer (score 0):

I'll denote by $\arcsin_s$ and $\arccos_s$ these two “shifted” functions.

Since $\arcsin_s x+\arccos_s x$ is easily seen to be constant, just compute it for $x=0$.

Why is it constant? Because the derivative of $\arcsin_s x$ is $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and the derivative of $\arccos_s x$ is $-1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (for $x\in(-1,1)$).